# Can I use Puppetmaster 3.2.x with Puppet 2.7 clients?

Tags: redhat, puppet, rhel6, puppetmaster

We are using RHEL 6.2 with Puppet 2.7 on about 100 servers.

I am planning to update the puppetmaster to RHEL 6.2 with Puppet 3.2. I understand that I have to rewrite a few manifests in order for the modules to work.

But does Puppet 3.2 support Puppet 2.7 clients or do I have to update all clients to 3.x too?

Comment: // , Would you please include an example of the sort of manifest that you think you'd need to rewrite, @ujjain?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll probably be fine but take a look at [THIS](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/whats_new.html#backwards-incompatible-changes-in-3x) as there are a few incompatibilities to be aware of.